# Binding across multiple ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple tabs in my wpf program, opening each of which loads a different UserControl.

On my main window, I have items such as a progress bar and tab headers that should be visible across all UserControls. Here's what my main window looks like

```html
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ValuesCheck></vm:ValuesCheck>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
  <ProgressBar Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="7" Padding="30" Name="pb_status" Value="{Binding pb_Value}" />
</Grid>

<TabControl>

  <TabItem Header="Introduction">
    <!--Code for My intro tab-->
  </TabItem>

  <TabItem Header="Step 1">
    <my:Step1 Loaded="Step1_Loaded" />
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Step 2" IsEnabled="{Binding step2Enabled}">
    <my:Step2 Loaded="Step2_Loaded" />
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Step 3" IsEnabled="{Binding step3Enabled}">
    <my:Step3 Loaded="Step3_Loaded" />
  </TabItem>

</TabControl>
```

For each user control, I have set the data context of the stack panel as a differnt ViewModel for each User Control. The stack panel has text boxes. Upon calling 'Set' of the 'Text' of the text boxes, the bound property checks the text and sets the 'brush' property bound to the borderbrush of the textbox. Thus, the user can see in real time if they are correct or wrong.

```
decimal _cAS;
public decimal cAS
{
    get { return _cAS; }
    set 
    {   
        _cAS = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("cAS");

        BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();
        if (_cAS<= 17 || _cAS >= 19)
            CASB= (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FF0000");
        else
            CASB = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#008000");
    }
}

System.Windows.Media.Brush _casb;
public System.Windows.Media.Brush CASB
{
    get { return _casb; }
    set { _casb = value; OnPropertyChanged("CASB"); }
}
```

```html
<TextBox Name="cAS" Text="{Binding cAS, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         BorderBrush="{Binding CASB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ...>
```

Now I don't know how to proceed. I want to enable the next tab and increase the progress bar on the press of a button on each tab. I am doing that in the code behind of the xaml.

```
private void proceed3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = DataContext as ViewModel.ValuesCheck;
    vm.step4Enabled = true;
}
```

How do I know in the code behind that all values are entered correctly. The data context for the button is the mainViewModel, not the particular ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for you case is create a [Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I would have a `MainViewModel` that looked something like this

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> Tabs { get; set; }
    int CurrentTabIndex { get; set; }
    int MaxTabIndex { get; set; }
    int Progress { get; set; }
    ICommand NextTab { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>();
        Tabs.Add(new Introduction());
        Tabs.Add(new Step1());
        Tabs.Add(new Step2());
        Tabs.Add(new Step3());

        Progress = 0;
        CurrentTabIndex = 0;
        MaxTabIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

The `NextTab` command's `CanExecute` would look something like this :

```
public bool NextTabCanExecute()
{
    // verify all tabs are valid so far
    for (int i = 0; i <= MaxTabIndex; i++)
    {
        if (Tabs[i].IsValid)
            return false;
    }

    // can't hit Next if we're on last tab    
    if (CurrentTabIndex == Tabs.Count - 1)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

while the `NextTab` command might look something like this

```
public void NextTab()
{
    if (CurrentTabIndex == Tabs.Count - 1)
        return; // on last tab already

    CurrentTabIndex++;

    // if user is on last enabled tab
    if (CurrentTabIndex == MaxTabIndex)
    {
        MaxTabIndex++;
        Progress += 100 / Tabs.Count;
    }
}
```

If the Next button has to be on the individual controls inside the Tab, then you could probably do something like

```
foreach(ITabViewModel tab in Tabs)
{
    tab.NextButtonCommand = this.NextTab;
}
```

There's probably a bunch of extra cases to check or tweaks to make, but this should hopefully give you a general idea.

Of course, your XAML would probably also need to be modified to support this.

---

As an alternative though, you could replace

```
ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> Tabs  { get; set; }
```

with specific objects, like this

```
IntroViewModel Intro { get; set; }
Step1ViewModel Step1 { get; set; }
Step2ViewModel Step2 { get; set; }
Step3ViewModel Step3 { get; set; }

bool IsStep1Enabled { get; set; }
bool IsStep2Enabled { get; set; }
bool IsStep3Enabled { get; set; }
```

and have your MainViewModel assign delegates to determine what should be enabled or what happens when you hit Next

```
Intro.NextDelegate = this.GoToStep1;
Step1.NextDelegate = this.GoToStep2;
Step2.NextDelegate = this.GoToStep3;

Step1.IsValidChanged += delegate { IsStep2Enabled = Step1.IsValid; }
Step2.IsValidChanged += delegate { IsStep3Enabled = Step2.IsValid; }
```

Personally I wouldn't like this, but it is an option :)

Comment: Okay, I think I got some of it. How do I check if the textboxes in each tab are entered correctly before proceeding to the new tab? Also, can you tell me more about the xaml design for this one. I am sorry, I am a beginner to programming in general!

Comment: @user2196163 I would have a `<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" ...>`, and use Implicit Data Templates to tell WPF how to draw each item type (IntroViewModel, Step1ViewModel, etc). You can use the `ItemContainerStyle` to bind the tab header to a property on the VM as well. Personally I would move the Next button outside of the TabControl, however that's not necessary. As for how to tell if textboxes on each tab are correct, have your TabViewModels implement `IDataErrorInfo` and you should have a property to identify if the TabViewModel IsValid or not.